# How to enable "Load unpacked extension" in canary and chrome developer edition?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have recently created my first chrome add in. When i am trying to run it in chrome developer version/canary i am getting "load unpacked extension" disabled. According to all the post i have searched this should be disabled in stable and beta version but not in developer edition.

Any solutions for this ?

[image]

Version 50.0.2661.18 dev-m

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of what it looks like disabled? You should be seeing a "Developer Mode" checkbox that you can select to show the "Load unpacked extension" button.

Comment: I have updated the post with screenshot

Comment: My _guess_ is that a policy is being applied. Can you check `chrome://policy/`?

Answer (score -1):

Just go to `chrome://extensions` in the URL bar.

Comment: This didn't work for me - that's exactly how I got to the page showing the disabled button